# Raster Calculator using GDAL

Tags: gdal, installation, raster-calculator, numpy

When I use the following code to perform some raster calculations with `gdal_calc.py`:

```
gdal_calc.py -A merged.tif --outfile= result.tif --cal="(A)/10000"
```

I get the following errors:

```
Module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6.
ImportError : numpy.core.multierror failed to import
```

Python Version :Python 2.7.2

Comment: this looks like an installation issue. Could you check that ? What is your OS ?

Comment: windows 10. installed pip from https://pip.pypa.io/

Comment: I would try to install Python and gdal with osgeo4W and run the command through the osgeo command prompt to make sure that the links are OK

Comment: Error says that you have wrong version of numpy. For checking what you have see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520234/how-to-check-which-version-of-numpy-im-using

Comment: it is 1.6 , i have install pip from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/ but when i write command on cmd it shows pip is not  recognize as internal or external command ,..... Is something i missed .. and how can i upgrade numpy version from 1.6 to 1.9 ?

Comment: Python version i am using Python 2.7.2